# How can jfrog command line set the Maven artifact group and version?

Tags: maven, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I can upload to Artifactory with `jfrog rt u mylibrary-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  myrepo-snapshot/com/mycompany/mylibrary/mylibrary-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` (I can do the same with curl and a simple HTTP call.)

However, this is just a single Jar file, whereas I need full Maven artifact details to go with it. When I use the Artifactory Maven Plugin and `mvn deploy`, I get the pom, the version number etc as here.

[image: From mvn deploy]

How do I do that with the  `jfrog` command line tool? (Or curl/HTTP.)